# SoapUI transferring a property

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I need to get a property from a response and use it in another request. After 2hrs of googling I am none the wiser...

I have the following XML response and I need to extract the COID value.

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <UsedRacfAccount xmlns="http://www.aaa.zz/webservices/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <Id>TestUser</Id>
      </UsedRacfAccount>
      <RequestInfo xmlns="http://www.aaa.zz/webservices/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <Id>20f4b4dc-d47e-40c8-9923-85a767e2b88f</Id>
      </RequestInfo>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <ZZ9V2P1Response xmlns="http://www.aaa.zz/webservices/ZZ9V2P1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <response>
            <SEVERITY-CODE>I</SEVERITY-CODE>
            <ROLLBACK-INDICATOR>N</ROLLBACK-INDICATOR>
            <ORIGIN-SERVERID>0</ORIGIN-SERVERID>
            <RETURN-CODE>1</RETURN-CODE>
            <REASON-CODE>1</REASON-CODE>
            <EXPORT-XXX>
               <COID>221000072015</COID>
               <KODE>N</KODE>
            </EXPORT-XXX>
         </response>
      </ZZ9V2P1Response>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I have added the Property Transfer step to check what, if anything, is read from the response and it looks like this...

[image: SoapUItransfer]

In theory I guess it should grab the COID and write it to coid property. But for all that is holy or unholy I cannot find any XPath that would return not only the coid, but anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the namespace. For just a transfer, you can use a wildcard: `//*:COID`.

Also, your screenshot says Property: **Request**, but your sample XML says: **response**.

Comment: Tried this also. The result is the same : Missing match for Source XPath [//*:COID]

Comment: @tom Request or response?

Comment: Sigh, nice catch. It seems after all the tinkering I managed to swap the source with target. After setting source property to Response and using wildcard for namespace everything works correctly. Thanks!